# cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.mailgun

Tags: php, laravel-4, mailgun

All of a sudden I have started getting this mailgun error ,

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException
>
> cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   api.mailgun.net:443

Any Mail gun user please help me out 
Thanks

Comment: I am getting the same error all of a sudden too.

Comment: Am also experiencing this, though it seems intermittent and works on retrying - perhaps an issue with Mailgun.

Comment: This is too bad :(

Comment: I just put in a ticket. We are using the API without Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue with Laravel 4.2 and Mailgun. I have contacted MG they are blaming this error on DDoS attacks they have been having. I included this thread in my latest support ticket. If you have any useful information to help them please include it here. I have noticed that it is only happening early to mid morning daily.

Mailgun's response 5/24/2016:

```
We made changes with our hosting provider late this morning that looks to have resolved the issue.  Please let us know if you continue experiencing this error.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error, but it is easy to solve and resolve for me!

Updating the version of php5-curl solved!
FOR UBUNTU => sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade php5-curl

enjoy! ;)

Comment: No it did not work for me , I am using Laravel Framework does that make any difference ??

Comment: Larval 5.1.*, and "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.2".

Comment: Laravel 4.2 is the version i am using for this project

Comment: part my .env file

`MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org`
`MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@magnat****`
`MAIL_PASSWORD=05ec****`
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

`MAILGUN_DOMAIN=magnatac***`
`MAILGUN_SECRET=key-****`

`FROM_ADDRESS = contato@magnatacal***`
`FROM_NAME = Magnata Ca**`

Comment: I was just using DOmain and Secret key in the service.php page , Do y0ou think If I upgrade the guzzle to 5.2 it will make any difference

Comment: Yes, try a older version, because you use 4.2 of laravel
[link]https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Try, another version for guzzle.

Comment: So to update guzzel I just have to add a different version in the Composer and then run composer update ?

Comment: you always run "composer update" and restar your server(apache, nginx, ...)

Answer (score -1):

I also getting the same issue. After debugging the code with try-catch what I noticed is, some of the recipient email ids have spaces like:

**testmail@google mail.com** instead of **testmail@googlemail.com**
may this answer give a way to solve your issue